# Создание RTS в Unity

Tags: unity3d, разработка-игр

Кто-нибудь знает книги по созданию RTS  на Unity(видеоуроки не предлагать, уж больно они унылые и запутанные).
Заранее спасбо за помощь!

Comment: Прежде чем браться за рыбу покрупнее, Вы бы попытались осилить "змейку" или "тетрис". Иначе не только видеоуроки, но и обучающие статьи будут казаться Вам унылыми и запутанными.

Comment: В том то и проблема, что делал уже и псевдошутер и подобие TD с одним уровнем. Но если честно, не особо люблю данные жанры. Поэтому и решил сесть за RTS, хоть и понимаю что это будет еще тем гемороем.
К стати да, интересные обучающие статьи тоже приветствуются.

Comment: Никто и никогда в жизни не напишет книгу о том, как создать полноценную игру, да еще и в таком редком жанре. Так что "унылые и запутанные видеоуроки" - чуть ли не единственное решение.

Comment: Я понимаю что книг с описанием полноценной игры нет и скорее всего не будет, особенно учитывая жанр. Так что за подобным я и не гонюсь. Мне бы просто статью бы какую-нибудь с описанием базовых механик в текстовом виде было бы уже шикарно.

Comment: Сделать нормальную RTS - это, как вы понимаете, сверхсложно. Задачи, которые вам предстоит решить, это: нахождение пути для ГРУПП! юнитов разной скорости и размера в условиях динамического и заранее неизвестного окружения (ты же не знаешь где враг блокирует проход), синхронизация игры между клиентами, расчет видимости карты и юнитов, баланс игры, ну и всякие мелочи вроде создания системы UI. На GDSE есть [сравнение](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/945/123089) сложности разных типов игр. Если сравнивать TD и RTS то это как рогатка и Тополь-М.

Comment: Боюсь написание RTS это уж больно унылое^1000 и запутанное^100 задача. То, что описал trollingchar, может заставить любого без мощной мотивации выгореть, как трифторид хлора.

Comment: Книгу не посоветую, но рекомендую вбить в google - rts unity tutorial. Выдаёт хорошие результаты. Без сарказма.

Answer (score 1):

Хоть и написано, что уроки не предлагать, хотелось бы посоветовать Романа Сакутина. Он крутой кодер и у него есть серия роликов по RTS (особенно он предлагает хорошие решения по коду) [Плейлист](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cphNyTSj5mY&list=PLOKAzMGgK9xuFn3v3P6Y7X4PZr237Qmtz)